# How do I know which registers to use in a MIPS Program

Tags: assembly, mips

I have been trying to learn MIPS Assembly language, but I am having a hard time knowing which registers to use in different situations. Like When do I use $v0 , $a0 or $t1...

Comment: We don't provide tutorials or recommend books. If your question can stand without the last paragraph, please edit it (lower left corner, "edit" link). If not, consider deleting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you don't use **any** code written by others, including system calls, you can use the registers however you want, provided that `$at` is reserved for the assembler and that `$ra` is implicitly used by `jal`/`jalr`.

It is *very* unlikely that you won't use any system call or any code written by others.
To let compilers and humans use routines without looking at their code, a convention is established among the experts.
It is called Application Binary Interface (ABI) and [MIPS got one too](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/mipsabi32.pdf).

The ABI mandates how the registers are used.
You have to respect the ABI whenever:

1. You use code that respect the ABI already.
   In this case the ABI is mostly informative, it tells you where the function is expecting the argument and what registers it uses.
2. When you want to be compatible with code or tools that expect the ABI.
   When you write a function, that you'll later give to a colleague, it is nice to write it respecting the ABI. This way they are already used to the convention and they'll find it natural to use it.
   If you use a compiler, it will surely compile the source code respecting the ABI and so it will expect any human generated assembly to do so.

Quoting the MIPS32 ABI these are the use of the registers:

> **$0 ($zero)** always has the value 0.
>
> **$at ($AT)** temporary generally used by assembler.  *[Never user it]*
>
> **$2..$3 ($v0–$v1)** used for expression evaluations and to hold the integer
>   and pointer type function return values. *[$v0 is where integers functions put their return value]*
>
> **$4..$7 ($a0–$a3)** used for passing arguments to functions; values are not
>   preserved across function calls. Additional arguments
>   are passed on the stack, as described below. *[This is where arguments go]*
>
> **$8-$15 ($t0–$t7)** temporary registers used for expression evaluation; values
>   are not preserved across function calls.
>
> **$16-$23 ($s0–$s7)** saved registers; values are preserved across function
>   calls. *[If you use these inside a function, save and restore them]*
>
> **$24..$25 ($t8–$t9)** temporary registers used for expression evaluations;
>   values are not preserved across function calls. When
>   calling position independent functions $25 must contain
>   the address of the called function.
>
> **$26-$27 ($kt0–$kt1)** used only by the operating system.
>
> **$28 ($gp)** global pointer and context pointer. *[Used by the compiler]*
>
> **$29 ($sp)** sp stack pointer. *[Use this for the stack]*
>
> **$30 ($s8)** saved register (like s0-s7). *[Save and restore this in functions if modified]*
>
> **$31 ($ra)** return address. The return address is the location to
>   which a function should return control. *[Set by `jal`/`jalr`]*